# Properties and states from decorators or parent properties?

Tags: reactjs, redux, decorator

I need to know what is most convenient way to implement. In my case, the parent component and the children component are using the same properties and states. My doubt is:

**1. Passing the properties from the parent component.**

[image]

[image]

**2. Use the decorators to set a properties values in the children component.**

[image]

[image]

advantages and disadvantages of different cases? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you're discovering is the distinction between Components and Containers.  Containers are what you refer to as "with decorators" and Components are those without.  There is a *lot* of discussion around best practices on these topics, and those keywords should make it easy to find lots of opinions.

Typically, the standard is that you should prioritize Components over Containers.  Components are abstract and reusable if created in the right way.  For instance, given your first example, I would modify it slightly to look more like this;

```
class ComponentParent extends React.Component {

    //...

    render() {
        <ComponentChildren onSomeEvent={this.props.optionActions.anyAction}/>;
    }
}

class ComponentChildren extends React.Component {

    //...

    someMethod() {
        this.props.onSomeEvent();
    }
}
```

When written this way, `ComponentChildren` can now be reused and given a new definition of `onSomeEvent` to interact with your app in a new way.  Building all of your components in this style will eventually lead to a library-like codebase, where code becomes *extremely* reusable.